# Why am I getting Node Error Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I have this simple server to play around express and node. I am getting this error when I call a function inside the `app.get()` method. I have serached around the internet and still I couldn't figure it out what's going in here.

Error

> ```
>  http_outgoing.js:518
>         throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
>         ^
>     
>     Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after 
>     they are sent to the client
>         at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:518:11)
>         at Array.write (G:\Project\Node Projects\Automater\node_modules\finalhandler\index.js:285:9)
>         at listener (G:\Project\Node Projects\Automater\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:169:15)
>         at onFinish (G:\Project\Node Projects\Automater\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:100:5)
>         at callback (G:\Project\Node Projects\Automater\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:55:10)
>         at IncomingMessage.onevent (G:\Project\Node Projects\Automater\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:93:5)
>         at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
>         at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)      
>         at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
>       code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
>     }
> ```

Here is my code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/user',(req,res,next) =>{
    log(req,res,next);
    res.send('user');
    
})

app.get('/',(req,res,next) => {
    res.send('Success');
});

function log(req,res,next){
    console.log('Logger !!!');
    next();
}
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: Here what I want to do is call a function inside `app.get()`. When I pass it like `app.get('/user',log,(req,res,next) =>{
    res.send('user');
})` it works fine. But when I call the `log()` function inside the fucntion just above `res.send()` it give this error

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `res.end()` because `res.send(...)` calls `res.write`, `res.setHeaders`, and `res.end` for you. When you call `res.send(...)` you already send response to client.

Comment: No even I remove the `res.end()`, it givem me the same error

Comment: It was already mentioned, but, yeah, you should also remove `next()` in the `log` function.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the response has already been sent to the client.

You are doing 2 things: res.send('user'); res.end();

Remove res.end() and it should be good.

Comment: No even I remove the `res.end()`, it givem me the same error

Comment: I believe that the log() function is just to log, in which case you can modify it like this :  

function log(){
    console.log('Logger !!!');
}